# Loading User Controls with jQuery .load()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I am using a clean test page, and loading a `user control` with jQuery's `.load()` function.
The current error I get is this:
`GET http://localhost:27950/OCDB/test.ascx 403 (Forbidden)`

Here is my Page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/test.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>This is a test.</title>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ucPlaceholder').load('test.ascx');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="ucPlaceholder">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my user control code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.ascx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<input placeholder="test input"/>
```

As you can see, its super simple. My immediate guess is that the page isn't picking up the `Register`. Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can directly call a user-control using jQuery.

But you can take help of generic http handler for it.

http://blog.ovesens.net/2008/12/dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery

Comment: I am having issues loading the `<httpHandlers>`... Its showing `Cannot resolve symbol` issues.

Comment: @NewAmbition in web config file?

Comment: Yes. But I realised the `IHttpHandler` needs to be in a `.cs` file. Now it works properly with `<add verb="*" path="*.ascx" type="jQueryHandler"/>` using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery.